# Newly installed Kubuntu does't have start menu

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu

this is my first time to install kubuntu. After i followed the steps to install and initially logged it, it displayed this page to me. It does't have the usual start or launch menu for me to access anything. I can't even start a terminal.

What's the problem? I can't even restart the system.

[image: Please see the image here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right mouse clicking on desktop and choosing "Add Panel" > "Default Panel". It should work.

Comment: Right!!! Why is like that?

Comment: I don't know, I am not experienced Kubuntu user.